# PHP cut string between two characters

Tags: php

How can I cut a string in PHP like these if I want to get the punycode?
I want to cut between the "(" and ")"

```
vizipipa.hu ekezet (xn--vzipipa-7ya.hu)
zoldtea.hu ekezet (xn--zldtea-wxa.hu)
uzletiakademia.hu ekezet (xn--zletiakadmia-jeb0x.hu)
ozon.hu ekezet (xn--zon-fna.hu)
```

So I want to get the punycodes as result like xn--zon-fna.hu
Thanks for the help

Comment: For future reference, had you included your PHP script and pointed out where you are stuck, your question might not have been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_match()` here:

```php
$input = "vizipipa.hu ekezet (xn--vzipipa-7ya.hu)";
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);  // xn--vzipipa-7ya.hu
```